# Replace a string in a list with a list of strings using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to replace the first string in the following list using the subsequent dictionary that is mapping to a list of strings.

```
id_list = ['40000', '58962', '85496']
id_dict = {'10000': ['10001','10002','10003'], '40000': ['40001','40002','40003']}
```

Using a defined function such as this:

```
def find_replace_multi_ordered(string, dictionary):
    # sort keys by length, in reverse order
    for item in sorted(dictionary.keys(), key = len, reverse = True):
        string = re.sub(item, dictionary[item], string)
    return string

# Credit: http://pythoninthewyld.com/2018/03/12/dict-based-find-and-replace-deluxe/
```

In the following for loop:

```
for i in id_list:

    if id_list[0][-4:] == '0000':
        id_list.replace(find_replace_multi_ordered(i, id_dict))

    else:
        pass

print(id_list)
```

This works for string to string dictionary mapping but results in a TypeError for sting to list mapping.

Error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The desired output would be the following:

```
id_list = [['40001','40002','40003'], '58962', '85496']
```

Thank you for any and all recommendations!

Comment: What happens if you type `id_dict['4000']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is much more easy, or each value of the list, if it's in the `dict` just replace by the pointed value, if it's absent keep the value

Detail of `id_dict.get(item, item)`

- first `item` is the key to look at, to retrieve a value
- second `item` is the default value, if the key has not been found

```
id_list = ['40000', '58962', '85496']
id_dict = {'10000': ['10001','10002','10003'], '40000': ['40001','40002','40003']}

id_list = [id_dict.get(item, item) for item in id_list]
print(id_list) # [['40001', '40002', '40003'], '58962', '85496']
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it do what you want?

```
id_list = ['40000', '58962', '85496']
id_dict = {'10000': ['10001','10002','10003'], '40000': ['40001','40002','40003']}

X = [
    item if item not in id_dict else id_dict[item] for item in id_list
]
print(X) # [['40001', '40002', '40003'], '58962', '85496']
```